# Quantum decoherence reversibility

Tags: quantum-mechanics, decoherence

Let us say we have a particle in a superposition of spin-up and spin-down at time $t_1$. The particle is measured as spin-up at time $t_2$ by an observer. At the current time, $t_3$ all traces of measurement is erased and lost by later interactions and fluctuations, the universe (including observer) is in exactly the same state, as it would be if the particle was measured as spin-down at $t_2$.

Question: Is decoherence at $t_2$ (that is in the past from current $t_3$) still "valid", or lost information about decoherence result means that the particle is considered in superposition at $t_2$, so the fact of decoherence happening itself is reversed? Maybe this is only a philosophical question, with no way even in theory to decide one way or another?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the premise of the question. How would the universe (including observer) end up in exactly the same state as if the outcome had been different? Erasing a record *in practice* (say, by melting the hard-drive) is not the same as erasing a record *in principle*. Decoherence works if the record cannot be erased *in principle*. Which of these two types of erasure do you have in mind when you say "exactly the same state"?

Comment: Observer died right after decoherence, so argument is simpler then. My assumption here is, that for some 2-state measurements, state of universe later in time can accidentaly get into the exactly same state, regardless which result decoherence had earlier. Like in snooker, balls a likely to get to same configuration twice, given enormous number of games we play.